# Exercise about repeated primitives

Tags: general-topology, continuity, baire-category

Suppose ${f}_{n}$ is a sequence of $C([0,1])$, ${f'}_{n+1}={f}_{n}$ for all $n$ and:

$\forall x \in [0,1]$, $\exists n$ : ${f}_{n}(x)=0$.

I want to show that ${f}_{1}$ is identically null!

So I think we should use Baire Theorem like this:    $E_{k}=${$x$ : ${f}_{k}(x)=0$}.

Then as $\bigcup_{n \geq 1} E_{n}$=$[0,1]$, there is an $E_{k}$ with non-empty interior, so $E_{k}$ contains an open interval!
I don´t know where to go from here, would apreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is proved in p.57 of 'A Primer of Real Functions' by R P Boas.

Comment: Use your idea not only on the interval $[0,1]$, but on arbitrary subintervals $[a,b]$. Then you get that $f\equiv0$ on some non-empty open subset of every closed subinterval. Can you see how that implies that $f\equiv0$ everywhere?